# Command `dotnet new -i` doesn't work for 5.0.7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, botframework

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cl

But when I run the following commands nothing happens.

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EchoBot
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.CoreBot
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EmptyBot
```

Just show the list of installed templates but none of the above included.

My `dotnet --info` output:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.301
 Commit:    ef17233f86

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.7
  Commit:  556582d964

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I tried both powershell and cmd, and also installed 3.1 Core

Edit:

Command `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EchoBot` output:

```
Template Name                                 Short Name           Language    Tags
--------------------------------------------  -------------------  ----------  ----------------------
Console Application                           console              [C#],F#,VB  Common/Console
Class library                                 classlib             [C#],F#,VB  Common/Library
WPF Application                               wpf                  [C#],VB     Common/WPF
WPF Class library                             wpflib               [C#],VB     Common/WPF
WPF Custom Control Library                    wpfcustomcontrollib  [C#],VB     Common/WPF
WPF User Control Library                      wpfusercontrollib    [C#],VB     Common/WPF
Windows Forms App                             winforms             [C#],VB     Common/WinForms
Windows Forms Control Library                 winformscontrollib   [C#],VB     Common/WinForms
Windows Forms Class Library                   winformslib          [C#],VB     Common/WinForms
Worker Service                                worker               [C#],F#     Common/Worker/Web
MSTest Test Project                           mstest               [C#],F#,VB  Test/MSTest
NUnit 3 Test Project                          nunit                [C#],F#,VB  Test/NUnit
NUnit 3 Test Item                             nunit-test           [C#],F#,VB  Test/NUnit
xUnit Test Project                            xunit                [C#],F#,VB  Test/xUnit
Razor Component                               razorcomponent       [C#]        Web/ASP.NET
Razor Page                                    page                 [C#]        Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewImports                               viewimports          [C#]        Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewStart                                 viewstart            [C#]        Web/ASP.NET
Blazor Server App                             blazorserver         [C#]        Web/Blazor
Blazor WebAssembly App                        blazorwasm           [C#]        Web/Blazor/WebAssembly
ASP.NET Core Empty                            web                  [C#],F#     Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)  mvc                  [C#],F#     Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web App                          webapp               [C#]        Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                     angular              [C#]        Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js                    react                [C#]        Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux          reactredux           [C#]        Web/MVC/SPA
Razor Class Library                           razorclasslib        [C#]        Web/Razor/Library
ASP.NET Core Web API                          webapi               [C#],F#     Web/WebAPI
ASP.NET Core gRPC Service                     grpc                 [C#]        Web/gRPC
dotnet gitignore file                         gitignore                        Config
global.json file                              globaljson                       Config
NuGet Config                                  nugetconfig                      Config
Dotnet local tool manifest file               tool-manifest                    Config
Web Config                                    webconfig                        Config
Solution File                                 sln                              Solution
Protocol Buffer File                          proto                            Web/gRPC

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new webapi
    dotnet new --help
    dotnet new nunit --help
```

Comment: Can you include the full output of `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EchoBot`?

Comment: what does it return when you execute dotnet new --list ?

Comment: Both commands return pretty much the same thing. I edited the post

Comment: Is this being done from an elevated prompt? Might try that as a test.

Comment: Maybe also try `dotnet new Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EchoBot --install  --interactive`

Comment: I run all commands in elevated prompt. Same output with --interactive too

Comment: Can you check the nuget sources? `dotnet nuget list source`. Here's what I have:
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Comment: The output was:
```
Registered Sources:
  1.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```
Probably that's the issue

Comment: I inserted the new source in Visual Studio. Probably this command would work as the well `dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org`. Everything is fine now. Thanks folks!